# Cannot create Foreign Key Constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

// Table Export From MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `pairs` (
  `parent` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `child` varchar(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `pairs` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`child`);
```

/----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Table Export From MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `dailyreports` (
  `SquareNo` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `notes` longtext,
  `dateReport` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `signed1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `signed2` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `dailyreport_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `dailyreports` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    declare SqNo varchar(5);
    declare CUser varchar(12);
    declare serNo INT;
    Set SqNo = new.SquareNo;
    Set CUser = new.id;
    Select Serial Into serNo from squareserials where Category ='DR' and SquareNo = SqNo;
    SET NEW.id = CONCAT(SqNo,'-DR',SUBSTRING('0000',1,4-LENGTH(CAST(serNo AS CHAR))),CAST(serNo AS CHAR));
    update squareserials set Serial = Serial +1 where Category ='DR' and SquareNo = SqNo;
    insert into activities (username,activity) values (CUser,CONCAT('Added Daily Report ',NEW.id));
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

ALTER TABLE `dailyreports` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SquareNo`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `dailyreports` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DR_SquareNo` FOREIGN KEY (`SquareNo`) REFERENCES `squareserials` (`SquareNo`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

/----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The below statement does not work, gives error "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint"

```
ALTER TABLE pairs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DR_Parent FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES dailyreports(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
ALTER TABLE pairs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DR_Parent FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES dailyreports(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

but

`id varchar(12) NOT NULL`,

in `dailyreports` is neither a primary nor unique. You can only refer a column which is `primary` or `unique` in base table to make foreign key. So make the column a key column or unique and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make `id` a unique along with Not Null.

Or make it Primary Key